# Why isn't there a sortBy method in ParSeq despite that there is one in Seq?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have this simple query to run and I want to parallelize it:

```
val res : Array[Int] = valuesRand
.groupBy(v => v)
.toSeq
.sortBy(_._1)
.map(_._2.size)
.toArray
```

Is the following the performant equivalent of my query?

```
val res : Array[Int] = valuesRand
.par
.groupBy(v => v)
.par
.toIndexedSeq
.sortBy(_._1)
.map(_._2.size)
.toArray
```

I am asking that, because I couldn't find the sortBy method into [ParSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq), although it exists in [Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.Seq).

Comment: I would guess that the Scala dev team did not implement a parallel sorting algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ParSeq](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParSeq) class does not directly extend [SeqLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.SeqLike) which provides for the `sortBy`. You can see this from the definition of [ParSeqLike](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.ParSeqLike):

```
trait ParSeqLike[+T, +Repr <: ParSeq[T], +Sequential <: scala.Seq[T] with SeqLike[T, Sequential]] extends GenSeqLike[T, Repr] with ParIterableLike[T, Repr, Sequential]
```

which ParSeq extends via

```
ParSeqLike[T, ParSeq[T], scala.Seq[T]]
```

Hence, only the `Splitter` in the underlying implementation is able to do a `sortBy` which does not help you one bit.